# Navigation Drawer Activity(On click Event)

Tags: android

I have a problem were to declare an onclickListerner sure that when an item is clicked on the Navigation Drawer it opens a new activity.I would attach the Java file which implements the Navigation drawer. Please under which method should i declare the onclick listener and what exactly am i declaring.

```
Home.java

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.AdapterView;

import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;


public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

{
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

private Toolbar toolbar;

private TabLayout tabLayout;

private ViewPager viewPager;

private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_card_giftcard_white_24dp,

        R.drawable.ic_card_membership_white_24dp,

        R.drawable.ic_map_white_24dp,

        R.drawable.ic_my_location_white_24dp,

        R.drawable.ic_star_rate_white_18dp,

        R.drawable.ic_delete_white_24dp,
};


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.nav);

     toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}



public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
   {
        return true;
    }


}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}



public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{


    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.favorite)
    {


    } else if (id == R.id.resturant)
    {

    } else if (id == R.id.account)
    {

    } else if (id == R.id.settings)
    {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share)
    {

    } else if (id == R.id.cassino)
    {

    }
    else if (id == R.id.park)
    {


    }
    else if (id == R.id.hotel)
    {

    }
    else if (id == R.id.post)
    {

    }
    else if (id == R.id.comments) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void setupTabIcons()
{
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(tabIcons[4]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(5).setIcon(tabIcons[5]);


}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
{
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
    adapter.addFragment(new FourFragment(), "FOUR");
    adapter.addFragment(new FiveFragment(), "FIVE");
    adapter.addFragment(new SixFragment(), "SIX");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }


    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title)
    {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}


}
```

If there is anything missing i am open to additions and suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for an onClickListener, there's already a [onNavigationItemSelected](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener.html#onNavigationItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) callback.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.favorite)
    {
        // start activity
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Got it @ginomempin pefert answer which worked tank u

Answer (score 1):

No need of **`onClickListner`**

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{


    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.favorite)
    {
          FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new "Your Activity()").commit();



    } else if (id == R.id.resturant)
    {    
         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new "Youractivity()").commit();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you User6880336 i appreciate